# Wrong interceptor is chosen when multiple bindings exist

Tags: ninject, ninject-interception

I have multiple implementations of an interface and I want to apply different interceptors for each of them e.g.:

```
public interface IFoo { int Run(); }

public class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public int Run() { return 1; }
}

public class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    public int Run() { return 2; }
}
```

Example interceptors:

```
public class MultiplyBy10 : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        invocation.Proceed();
        invocation.ReturnValue = (int)invocation.ReturnValue * 10;
    }
}

public class MultiplyBy100: IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        invocation.Proceed();
        invocation.ReturnValue = (int)invocation.ReturnValue * 100;
    }
}
```

Binding:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo1>().Named("1");
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo2>().Named("2");

kernel.Intercept(ctx => ctx.Plan.Type == typeof(Foo1)).With<MultiplyBy10>();
kernel.Intercept(ctx => ctx.Plan.Type == typeof(Foo2)).With<MultiplyBy100>();
```

I expect Foo1 to be multiplied by 10 and Foo2 by 100. But instead both are multiplied by 10 i.e.:

```
var foo1 = kernel.Get<IFoo>(ctx => ctx.Name == "1");
var foo2 = kernel.Get<IFoo>(ctx => ctx.Name == "2");

Assert.That(foo1.Run(), Is.EqualTo(10));
// fails: returns 20
Assert.That(foo2.Run(), Is.EqualTo(200));
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I reproduced your issue and it happens with both Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProx and Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Linfu. I saw that you have already filed an issue here: http://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.interception/issues/26

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug. It's now fixed on master: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.interception/commit/fb5ca07c287e4c61f630e8da7ba6fd827ce6be85